# Specific textview from listview using OnClick?

Tags: android, listview, onclick, textview

Hi I have a question. Wondering how do I get certain values from the OnItemClick method. I can get position but seen as I have more then 1 textview in this position is it possible to get the first textview?

Heres my code

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    for(int i=0; i<poi.length; i++){

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("first", poi[i][0]);
    map.put("second",poi[i][1]);
    mylist.add(map);

}

    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.row,
                new String[] {"first", "second"}, new int[] {R.id.FIRST, R.id.SECOND});
    list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("owen", Integer.toString(position));

//my code to get "first" string on click
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the resource identifier for the desired textview, you can take the view passed into the onitemClick() method and find that child:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    TextView myText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
    Log.i("owen", myText.getText().toString());
}
```

The position relates to the row position in the AdapterView list.